# c++, reading from a file to a struct and then to a vector (the structs are pushed into the vector too many times instead of just once)

Tags: c++, vector, struct

so we just started c++ and i am trying to read from a file into a struct and then push it into a vector, but it pushes the same things multiply times...what am i doing wrong?

```
 void StreamToVector(vector<ChemicalForm>& Formulas, int CC, int HC, string 
Chemical){
    if (Formulas.size() == 0) {
        ChemicalForm Chem;
        Chem.C = CC;
        Chem.H = HC;
        Chem.ChemicalNames.push_back(Chemical);
        Formulas.push_back(Chem);
    }
    else {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Formulas.size(); ++i) {
            if (Formulas[i].C == CC && Formulas[i].H == HC) {
                Formulas[i].ChemicalNames.push_back(Chemical);
                ++count;
            }
        if (count == 0) {
            ChemicalForm Chem;
            Chem.C = CC;
            Chem.H = HC;
            Chem.ChemicalNames.push_back(Chemical);
            Formulas.push_back(Chem);
        }

        }
    }

int main() {
    string File = OpenFile();
    ifstream ChemFile(File);
    vector<ChemicalForm> Formulas;
    string Chemical;
    int CC;
    int HC;
    char c;
    char h;
    while (ChemFile >> Chemical>> c >> CC>> h >>HC) {
        StreamToVector(Formulas, CC, HC, Chemical);
    }
```

i am expected to read from this file:

n-Butane C4H10
Propyne C3H3
1,3-Butadiyne C4H2
Hexane C6H14
Butane C4H10
iso-Butane C4H10
Pentane C5H12

and the expected output is:
C3H3 Propyne
C4H2 1,3-Butadiyne
C4H10 n-Butane Butane iso-Butane
C5H12 Pentane
C6H14 Hexane

meaning, if two Chemicals has the same formula they go together. i know for sure the problem is the last if statement but i'm not sure what exactly.
this is the output i get:

C3H10 n-Butane Butane iso-Butane
C4H3 Propyne Propyne
C4H2 1,3-Butadiyne 1,3-Butadiyne
C4H2 1,3-Butadiyne 1,3-Butadiyne
C5H14 Hexane Hexane
C5H14 Hexane Hexane
C5H14 Hexane Hexane
C5H14 Hexane Hexane
C5H12 Pentane Pentane
C5H12 Pentane Pentane
C5H12 Pentane Pentane
C5H12 Pentane Pentane
C6H12 Pentane Pentane
C6H12 Pentane Pentane
C6H12 Pentane Pentane
C6H12 Pentane Pentane

Comment: The code looks ok to me. Please create a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: There is a loop there that calls `push_back()` multiple times, and pushes the same chemical multiple times into different vectors.   In any case, your question is not clear.   There is no information about how you determine that anything is pushed multiple times.    You need to provide an example of expected input and output (or description of what you expect the various vectors to contain, and how that differs from the result you get).   Without that information, nobody can explain what is right or wrong in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is with the `else` block:

```
else {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Formulas.size(); ++i) {
        if (Formulas[i].C == CC && Formulas[i].H == HC) {
            Formulas[i].ChemicalNames.push_back(Chemical);
            ++count;
        }
    if (count == 0) {
        ChemicalForm Chem;
        Chem.C = CC;
        Chem.H = HC;
        Chem.ChemicalNames.push_back(Chemical);
        Formulas.push_back(Chem);
    }

    }
}
```

In C++, brackets determine which expressions belong to the same block. In your code, the `if (count == 0)` part is actually part of the `for`-loop, which means that if a chemical has not yet been found in the vector (i.e. `count == 0`), then it would be pushed into the vector each time the loop is executed.

To fix this, simply put the `if`-statement outside of the `for`-loop:

```
else {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Formulas.size(); ++i) {
        if (Formulas[i].C == CC && Formulas[i].H == HC) {
            Formulas[i].ChemicalNames.push_back(Chemical);
            ++count;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        ChemicalForm Chem;
        Chem.C = CC;
        Chem.H = HC;
        Chem.ChemicalNames.push_back(Chemical);
        Formulas.push_back(Chem);
    }
}
```

As a good practice, it helps to properly indent your code according to nested levels. Having a tidy code style is the first step to writing good code.

Comment: Fixed it, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You have some misleading indentation, or misplaced curly braces, depending on how you look at it.  If you match the braces in `StreamToVector` carefully, you'll see that your `if (count == 0)` code is actually inside the `for` loop searching for an existing formula with matching `C` and `H`.

So for example if the data to be added matches the third existing `ChemicalForm` in the vector, the `for` loop will check the first element, then add a new `ChemicalForm` since `count` is still zero, then check the second element, then add a new `ChemicalForm` again since `count` is still zero, then modify the third element and set `count` to one.

Most likely you meant for the `if (count == 0)` code to come after the `for` loop finishes, so that either one `ChemicalForm` is modified, or else one new `ChemicalForm` is added.

A tool like clang-format, or a code editor's automatic indenting/reformatting feature can force the code to be indented according to where the braces actually are, which might have helped you notice the issue.

As an aside, once that issue is fixed, you won't need the `if (Formulas.size() == 0)` check.  The other code will be correct in that case too: the `for` loop over an empty vector will do nothing at all, so of course `count` will still be zero, so a new `ChemicalForm` will be added.